# How to design Django models where one key have multiple corresponding values?

Tags: python, django, orm

For example I have data:

```
key:     unique value:
value1   672345
value1   823764
value1   478214
value1   123575
value2   866323
value2   967386
```

Unique values stored in one table, which preferably must not be touched.
Also, to multiple unique values can be assigned one key. 
Another table would contain a column with unique keys.

What good design approach in Django to express this relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple model demonstrating how you can define a model and a field:

```
from django.db import models

class Value(models.Model):
    val = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class Key(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.ManyToManyField(Value, related_name='values')
```

That's how you can query on models to get key and its values:

```
from myApp.models import Key, Value # where myApp is your app name

key = Key.objects.get(key='my_key')
values = key.values.all()
```

Comment: In `OneToMany` `Foreign Key` should be added to table with unique values, right? Also - if using models listed in answer - it is impossible to retrieve vals corresponding to key from `Key` object? Can you add example of such retrieving please?

Comment: You required `ManyToMany` i have updated my answer. I'll put example of how to retrieve values from key object.